# How to use template to show a model(kind) which has one-to-many relationship?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two models, like this:

```
class A(db.Model):
    propertyA = db.XxxProperty(required=True)

class B(db.Model):
    reference = db.ReferenceProperty(A,collection_name='Bs',required=Ture)
    propertyB = db.XxxProperty(required=True)
```

Now, I want to show information of all the As using template. In python file, I do:

```
As = A.all().filter('propertyA =', XXX).fetch(10)
```

I pass As to template, like this:

```
{% for a in As%}
    {{a.propertyA}}
    *****SHOW EVERY B THAT a HAS*****
{% endfor%}
```

Here is the problem, each A may have many Bs, and I need something like this:

```
a_has_these_Bs = a.BS
for b in a_has_these_Bs:
    b.propertyB
```

But how can I put query stuff above into template?
Is there any other way to implement my intention?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `collection_name` is for. `A` has a property `Bs`, which is a query that returns those `B` objects that refer to `A`.

So you want something like `{% for b in a.Bs %}`, although I don't have anything handy to test that in.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a @property function

```
class A(db.Model):
    propertyA = db.XxxProperty(required=True)

    @property
    def has_these_bs(self):
        objs = B.all().filter('reference =', self)
        return [b for b in objs]

class B(db.Model):
    reference = db.ReferenceProperty(A,collection_name='Bs',required=Ture)
    propertyB = db.XxxProperty(required=True)
```

then in the template:

```
for b in a.has_these_Bs:
    b.propertyB
```

of course its not the best solution to do `B.all().filter('reference =', self)` and then loop over that query. it would be a lot better to fetch a result like `B.all().filter('reference =', self).fetch(500)` if you know how many Bs the entity A has or the max number it could have.

Comment: Thank you for offering me this amazing way using decorator.